# Wrong Redirection

Tags: redirect

My website's login page i.e `techisthenewcool.tk/wp-admin` is redirecting to website's homepage. I don't know why its happening. I tried googling for it and found no results. I use Hostinger India free hosting service.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we don't and can't know either. Yes, the redirect seems to be happening. No, it's not possible to guess *why* from outside. It might be something in your WP installation, it might be something on web server level.

On WordPress side [Better HTTP Redirects](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-http-redirects/) plugin can help debug redirects, but since you don't have access to admin there isn't even a way to easily install and enable it.